# Strange set state behaviour inside .then block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pulling data from a firebase collection `cafes` into a React component called `CafeReviews`, and then setting that data into a state variable called `cafe`.
The data coming back has the following shape:

```
{
 name: cafe name,
 photoURL: photo url
}
```

The strange behavior is that sometimes the data renders to the browser, but other times the browser crashes and gives the following error:

`TypeError: cafe.data() is not a function`

I'm assuming this is an async error - that the browser is loading the component before the state has been set. So how do I set state within a `.then` block, that itself is within the `useEffect` hook?

Here's the component in full:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import db from '../fbConfig'

const CafeReviews = ({match}) => {

    const [cafe,setCafe] = useState([])
    let id = match.params.id

 useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('cafes')
        .doc(id)
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          setCafe(snapshot)
        })
    },[])

    return(
        <div>
           <h1>{cafe.data().name}</h1> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default CafeReviews
```

Comment: Why would you expect cafe.data to be a function? When is that method defined?

Comment: Do you want to display a list of cafes or one cafe in this Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial state for `cafe` is `[]`, so when you call `cafe.data()` on that, it gives the error you get. You need to make sure that your rendering code handles both the initial state and the data from the database, typically by ensuring they have the same shape.

For example:

```
const [cafe,setCafe] = useState({ name: "loading..." })
```